# django get file size and put it in serializer

Tags: django

**serializers.py**

```
class ModFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    size = serializers.CharField(default=os.path.getsize('file'), max_length=16)
    class Meta:
        model = models.ModFile
        fields = '__all__'

        read_only_fields = (
        'size',
        )
```

**models.py**

```
class ModFile(models.Model):
    downloads = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='mods/')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here I have a serializer for the ModFile model and the only thing that's missing is the file's size, I know os.path.getsize() needs the exact location of the file so how do I actually access the file field from the model in order to pass in the getsize() function or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ModFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    size = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_size(self, obj):
        return os.path.getsize(obj.file.path)
        
    class Meta:
        model = models.ModFile
        fields = '__all__'

        read_only_fields = (
            'size',
        )
```

I think this would work any time you use this serializer.

`obj` in the get_size method is the instance itself.

Comment: You don't even need `os.path....`. `obj` is a `ModFile` instance, then if you access `obj.file` you have a [FieldFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile) instance and you can normally simply return `obj.file.size` or other fields available on a [FieldFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile) instance.

Comment: This gives an error. Other test pass for the same file. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/project/media/styles/image_graded.svg'

Answer (score 1):

Add a `to_representation` method to your serializer which is much easy.

```
class ModFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ModFile
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super(ModFileSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        rep['size'] = instance.file.size
        return rep
```

Comment: @Lun Are you sure you have written it correctly? You didn't add the ```to_representation``` in ```Meta``` class, did you?

Comment: I did, maybe the problem is how I'm handling things in the apiview, thanks for helping!

Comment: @Lun Can you provide the view?